How do I run down whats consuming the disk space on this EC2 instance?
A process stopped running. I went to disable the job and can't even access crontab. The instance was provisioned with about 15GB.
$ crontab -e
/tmp/crontab.QdgWmI: No space left on device
Creation of temporary crontab file failed - aborting

When checking the space used there are about 8.5 GB accounted for using du:
sudo du -cha --max-depth=1 / | grep -E "M|G"
139M    /boot
791M    /snap
2.3G    /usr
4.4G    /home
287M    /run
du: cannot access '/proc/380392/task/380392/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/380392/task/380392/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/380392/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/380392/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
575M    /var
2.2M    /tmp
7.2M    /etc
8.4G    /
8.4G    total

df though indicates all 15GB are used.
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        15G   15G     0 100% /
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.2G  295M  2.9G  10% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/xvda16     881M  133M  687M  17% /boot
/dev/xvda15     105M  6.1M   99M   6% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G   12K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
This instance should be stateless so I'm not even sure where to start looking. 

Targeting different locations with du hasn't uncovered anything that looks exceptional.

Deleted, but still open, files?

Check your logs - is logrotate succeeding?  Perhaps something is writing a log file that keeps getting bigger. The lsof (LiSt Open Files)  will help you find big, open files. Run sudo lsof .... Also check /var.

It was a deleted log held open by a service that was killed. Thanks all
